# Reason to run a fridge compressor fan other than when compressor running

Tags: hvac, refrigerator, cooling, freezing

In regard to a small sailing yacht galley fridge, would there be any reason/benefit/need to run the compressor radiator fan any time outside of that which the compressor is running itself ?

Ie just have the fan running off the compressor terminals ??

Thanks !

Comment: Possibly the compressor radiator fan is used in the automatic defrost function. (Disclaimer: I do not know the details of how modern refrigerators function)

Comment: The fan for some condenser coils are temperature controlled making sure all the heat is removed.  Turning the fan off it may cause problems with the system's ability to control the temperature the make and model would be helpful.

Comment: The moment the compressor shuts off, the condenser is rather hot.  It is good for the fan to remove that last bit of heat.  Is the fridge discharging heat into the cabin's air, or into water?

Comment: Close as "unclear what you're asking."  Does the fridge come with this fan, and does it run forever or just for a period of time after the compressor turns off?

Comment: It is a simple danfoss 101N0210 controller, there is no freezer component so no defrost. currently it just has 12v output for the fan and run continuously (on purpose) regardless of temperature or compressor state. Ive bought a small temperature controlled relay circuit to put in between, so the fan only runs when the temperature on the piping dictates its need. But had got to thinking if that was even necessary, and if it could just be run off the compressor supply for simplicity.

Comment: Using a temp switch is a good idea to save energy on your boat. The fan will be needed to cool the heated freon based on the condenser temp. If you do set this up don't set the temp two high or you may find the compressor cycling more often drawing more power than the constantly running fan would.

Comment: Is the condenser cabinet excessively warm, e.g. due to high solar load? Does it do this at night? Because the unit may sense that and run the fan to make the space cool enough for the condenser to be effective.   If not,  from these imstructions my guess is your unit is defective.  It's clear the unit is meant to control a fan in a meaningful way.  Attach the LED and see if you get a fault code.    http://files.danfoss.com/TechnicalInfo/Dila/06/BD35-50F_101N0210-20-40_0300-20_08-2011_dehcei100b602.pdf

Comment: That is the manual I found online for it too. What gives you the impression it does anything other than run the fan all the time which was what I got from the manual... There is a led hooked up. I don't think there is any error code but I'll check again, not that there is any relevant to my situation. Fan runs always all night and it is that reason of noise and not power waste that is more the reason I'm doing this

Comment: Seems I was mistaken, it does turn the fan off  itself the moment the compressor stops after all...